# Check if element is in viewport doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript

I've got three elements - every element is hidden from the start. If user scrolls onto them, they show up. I wrote a function that checks if element named *bubbles* is inside viewport. If it is, then function should show the rest of the elements.

But it doesn't. Element *boxes* is higher than element *bubbles*, and it also fires a function. But it shouldn't. I have no idea where the problem is.

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", checkViewport);

function checkViewport() {

  var bubbles = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble-chat");
  var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("boxes");
  var avatar = document.getElementsByClassName("msg-avatar");

  for (let i = 0; i < avatar.length; i++) {
    var bounding = bubbles[i].getBoundingClientRect();

    if (
      bounding.top >= 0 &&
      bounding.left >= 0 &&
      bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
      bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    ) {
      avatar[i].style.opacity = "1";
      bubbles[i].style.opacity = "1";
      (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          bubbles[i].style.display = "none";
          boxes[i].style.opacity = "1";
        }, 3000);
      })(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should also consider the scrolling positioning as the bounding box is relative to that.
Fixed code:

```
  bounding.top >= document.documentElement.scrollTop &&
  bounding.left >= 0 &&
  bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
  bounding.bottom <= document.documentElement.scrollTop + (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
```

Comment: It works better, but still not as good as I expected. In some cases, bubbles are shown after message text. It's really important to show bubbles (facebook like typing animation), and then msg-text (text message).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel stupid. The code was okay all the time. I just commented one of the *msg-text* divs, and turns out, that it was the reason for the code to break.